# How to get soft keyboard touch event letters using xamamrin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, keyboard

In a research project I need to obtain the touch event when the user is typing with a soft keyboard. Basically I am implementing the soft keyboard. So I was wondering if there is a way that I can set a touch Listener for the view of the existing soft keyboard and get both the touch event and the text?

Answer (score 0):

The soft keyboard is a completely separate app.  You cannot put a touch handler or get any touch input from it.  The only way to do what you want is to write the keyboard yourself (or use an open source one and instrument it).

Comment: okey dude. if there any possible to create own keyboard and replace the system keyboard in android mobile like a service. when i use other apps i want to use our new keyboard. (can you give me some ideas? pls)

Comment: Yes, you can replace the keyboard. You just need to write a service that extends InputMethodService and send the keys pressed via InputConnection. A full tutorial is too big for this site, but you can find some online. You can also find Google's open source keyboard, LatinIME to use as a starting point